# Replace values only if they are different

Tags: c, regex, vcf-vcard

I have a vcf file like this:
http://www.1000genomes.org/node/101

Here's the example from that site:

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.0
##fileDate=20090805
##source=myImputationProgramV3.1
##reference=1000GenomesPilot-NCBI36
##phasing=partial
##INFO=<ID=NS,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Number of Samples With Data">
##INFO=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total Depth">
##INFO=<ID=AF,Number=.,Type=Float,Description="Allele Frequency">
##INFO=<ID=AA,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Ancestral Allele">
##INFO=<ID=DB,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="dbSNP membership, build 129">
##INFO=<ID=H2,Number=0,Type=Flag,Description="HapMap2 membership">
##FILTER=<ID=q10,Description="Quality below 10">
##FILTER=<ID=s50,Description="Less than 50% of samples have data">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=GQ,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Genotype Quality">
##FORMAT=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Read Depth">
##FORMAT=<ID=HQ,Number=2,Type=Integer,Description="Haplotype Quality">
#CHROM POS     ID        REF ALT    QUAL FILTER INFO                              FORMAT      NA00001        NA00002        NA00003
20     14370   rs6054257 G      A       29   PASS   NS=3;DP=14;AF=0.5;DB;H2           GT:GQ:DP:HQ 0|0:48:1:51,51 1|0:48:8:51,51 1/1:43:5:.,.
20     17330   .         T      A       3    q10    NS=3;DP=11;AF=0.017               GT:GQ:DP:HQ 0|0:49:3:58,50 0|1:3:5:65,3   0/0:41:3
20     1110696 rs6040355 A      G,T     67   PASS   NS=2;DP=10;AF=0.333,0.667;AA=T;DB GT:GQ:DP:HQ 1|2:21:6:23,27 2|1:2:0:18,2   2/2:35:4
20     1230237 .         T      .       47   PASS   NS=3;DP=13;AA=T                   GT:GQ:DP:HQ 0|0:54:7:56,60 0|0:48:4:51,51 0/0:61:2
20     1234567 microsat1 GTCT   G,GTACT 50   PASS   NS=3;DP=9;AA=G                    GT:GQ:DP    0/1:35:4       0/2:17:2       1/1:40:3
```

After the header lines, each line has fields that contain genotypes starting with the 10th field. The 10th field is below the `NA0001` heading; the 11th field is genotype `NA0002`, etc. I have a file with 123 different genotypes, so going from position 10 to 133 (NA0001 until NA0123). What is shown in these fields can be 0/0, 0/1, 0/2 .... till 8/9 for instance. Now I want to replace all the non-equal ones. So I would like to keep 0/0, 1/1, 2/2, etc. And replace 0/1, 0/2, 1/2, 4/5, 4/6 etc by ./.

I would like to write this in a C script. Thought about using sed y/regexp/replacement/ but no idea how to write all those unequal values in a regular expression. And on other positions in the file there could also be these values, so really only positions 10 till 133 should be replaced. And it needs to be replaced; I will be needing the rest of the file with the new values.

Hope it is clear. Anyone any idea how to do this?

Comment: Are you saying you want to replace something like `0/1` with the literal `./.` (period, slash, period)?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do what you want: `\s(\d)[|\/](?!\1)\d:` Replace matches with `./.:`

**Breakdown:**

`\s(\d)` matches a space followed by a single digit, capturing the digit in capture group #1

`[|\/]` matches a pipe or slash (since it seems that the VCF format allows either)

`(?!\1)\d` uses a negative lookahead to ensure that the next character is not the same as capture group #1, and matches the digit

**Caveats:**

I matched a leading space and trailing `:` to try to ensure it matches only the intended values. I couldn't work out a good way to limit it to fields 10 and after.

**Example using perl:**

```
perl -pe 's@\s(\d)[|/](?!\1)\d:@ ./.:@g' testfile.vcf > testfile_afterchange.vcf
```

Note: I used `@` as the delimiter to avoid having to escape the `/` characters in the regex.

Comment: So then I type this: cat testfile.vcf | sed 'y/\s(\d)[|\/](?!\1)\d:/\./\./ > testfile_afterchange.vcf but I get the error sed: -e expression #1, char 26: strings for 'y' command are different lengths. So I also tried it with 's/old/new/' but is not working as well, char 28: invalid back reference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user4311883: Well, you've got several problems trying to use `sed`. The `y` command is a transform, not a regex substitution, so you need to use `s`. sed regex doesn't support `\d` (use `[0-9]` instead). Also, in sed, parens for grouping need to be escaped. The show-stopper, though, is that sed doesn't support lookarounds. I'll add a perl solution to my answer, hoping you can use perl instead.

Comment: The script works for half of it. I count the outcome per value combination. For the testfile the outcome is like this: 1408: ./. 3596: 0/0 746: 0/1 31: 0/2 1: 0/3 2: 0/4 2518: 1/1 20: 1/2 67: 2/2 5: 3/3 2: 4/4 1: 6/6  and now the outcome of the testfile_afterchange is like this: 614: have nothing, just blank space 1194: ./. 4491: 0/0 2041: 1/1 56: 2/2 1: 3/3. So total number for both files is still the same, nothing is lost, but the non-equal ones seem to have changed to blank space and some of the equal ones as well. Any idea?

Comment: @user4311883: I don't understand because I don't have your testfile, so it's hard to see what you're saying. I understand if you don't want to post your real data. Can you try it on the sample file I took from the 1000genomes site to see how it works? Were you able to use perl?